# RGB Chicklet Keyboard

Tags: keyboards

I love playing video games, however as it is not a full-time hobby of mine, as I write a lot I am uncomfortable with any other keycaps and I do not want a mechanical keyboard. I am looking for a **chicklet key, RGB illuminated (or yellow backlighting), silent keyboard**. The only one I have found matching my requirements is the Razer Deathstalker Chroma. While it does look neat and seems perfect for my needs, I find it a bit expensive and am wondering I there isn't a cheaper option.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some further google searching could find a few more results, but it seems chiclet keyboards with RGB LEDs are few and far between.  I did however find this Steelseries https://steelseries.com/gaming-keyboards/apex-350, it might not be what your are looking for exactly, but it is low profile, RGB, and not mechanical.  Not sure if cheaper than the Razer.

Comment: Thanks, actually I have already looked at this keyboard - which looks nice too - but it is even more expensive than the Deathstalker :/